# PHP - Avoid reloading page after form submit

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I'm new to php and web-programming... I'm working on a school project modifying databases through a corporate site.

I'm using some forms to allow the user to look for information that will be used to fill up other forms on the same page. In this case, a car rental, I look for available cars, show them on a table and then the user picks a car and its info would fill up some other inputs on the same page.

I'm able to do the search and show the result, but then when the user picks the car and clicks submit the whole page is uploaded again. Please, any suggestions?

J.

Comment: Use Ajax.......

Comment: Agreed -- AJAX.  Start with the jQuery library... and welcome to web programming.

Comment: Ohhh nooo all these answers are SOOO wrong! I know exactly what you mean, the problem is the handling of POST-data. There's a common technique on that, i will just search my stuff an then write a big answer.

Comment: ok, I did a js script to get the variable from the form without updating and now... how do I pass that js variable to php using a post????

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to a different page/route, other than the one page was submitted to.

An example for different page redirection.

```
header("location: differentpage.php");
exit;
```

Once you are in `differentpage.php` you cannot reload the POST request. TO get the data you can use `SESSION` or `GET` parameter as per requirements.

Comment: This still counts as a whole page load, and the original question was looking to avoid that, I think.

Comment: Not necessarily, since the page arrives at `differentpage.php` it is no longer associated with submiting page directly.

Comment: Very bad practice, in in reality [modern site just live within ONE index.php] this is useless.

Comment: @Panique, Even single page websites have different routes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in JavaScript, not in PHP.

PHP is a server-sided language, what you do is parsed on the server side.

To stop a form submission you need to use JavaScript. Set an onSubmit event on your form..

Example code:

```
<script>
  function validation()
  {
    // do stuff

    return false; // stops submission of form
  }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return validation();">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Read the question once again.

Comment: @Starx why? The question stats he wants to avoid reloading the page. With your method page would get reloaded. The clear path is to deny form submission & use AJAX to get the data for the other forms he wnats to fill out..

Comment: ok, but I did lot of code in php already so I thought about just passing the form parameters to php through JS...

Comment: @Johan, Because you haven't answered a single thing answered by the question. Not even the AJAX part which you claim to be answering.

Comment: @Starx, he asked how to prevent page from reloading. Your answer does the opposite of that..

Comment: @user2108393 then you should look at AJAX as others have suggested. Since you're new to it, perhaps look into jQuery to ease things :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use javascript and ajax you can use an iframe and set the target of the form as the iframe's name

note that you have to write 2 different pages to achieve this:

1. One that creates the form and the iframe
2. One that display data and uses posted values

**Code in index.html**

```
<form action="test.php" target="tar">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="tar">
</iframe>
```

**Code in test.php**

```
var_dump($_POST); // show your data
```